# JSP Page Will Not Open in Eclipse

Tags: java, html, database, eclipse, jsp

Okay, so I have a weird situation. I basically created this JSP page that was working previously, or at least in the sense that Eclipse would open a new tab with the page displayed when I ran the code. But today, when I went back in to look at the form I had created, it basically flashes the new tab for a second and then automatically closes. I am not getting any errors in the console or the tomcat logs, so I'm not sure what is going on. I tried creating a new JSP file (without the same code) in the same project and it loaded correctly. Has anyone had any experience with a similar issue?

Below is my code...

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                <title>Code Selector</title>
        </head>
        <body> 
            <h1>Please select the applicable codes:</h1> 
            <select name='Code' onchange="showState(this.value)">  
            <option value="none">Select a code</option>  
            <%
                //Pulls the ids and decriptions from the codes table and stores them in the first drop down
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("driverName").newInstance();  
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("serverURL","username","password");  
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, descr from codes");

                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        %>
                            <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%> <%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
                        <%
                    }

                    //Closes the database connection
                    stmt.close();
                    con.close();
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                } 
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Generic Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }       
            %>
            </select>  
            <br>
            <br>
            <select name='Code2' onchange="showState(this.value)">  
            <option value="none">Select a code</option>  
            <%
                //Pulls the ids and decriptions from the codes table and stores them in the second drop down
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("driverName").newInstance();  
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("serverURL","username","password");  
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, descr from codes");

                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        %>
                            <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%> <%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
                        <%
                    }

                    //Closes the database connection
                    stmt.close();
                    con.close();
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                } 
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Generic Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }       
             %>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <select name='otherCode' onchange="showState(this.value)">  
            <option value="none">Select a other code</option>  
            <%

                //Pulls the ids and decriptions from the other codes table and stores them in the third drop down
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("driverName").newInstance();  
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("serverURL","username","password");  
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select id, descr from other_codes");

                    while(rs2.next())
                    {
                        %>
                            <option value="<%=rs2.getString(1)%>"><%=rs2.getString(1)%> <%=rs2.getString(2)%></option>  
                        <%
                    }

                    //Closes the database connection
                    stmt.close();
                    con.close();
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                } 
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Generic Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }       
            %>
      </select>
      <br> 
      <br>
      <form method = "post">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <%
            try
            {
                String Code = request.getParameter("Code");
                String Code2 = request.getParameter("Code2");
                String otherCode = request.getParameter("otherCode");

                Class.forName("driverName").newInstance();  
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("serverURL","username","password");  
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                //ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery();

                System.out.println("This is the first code: " + Code);
                System.out.println("This is the second code: " + Code2);
                System.out.println("This is the other code: " + otherCode);

                con.close();
                stmt.close();

            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
            } 
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Generic Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            } 
        %>
        <script>
            window.close();
        </script>
      </form>
      </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: um, this might sound silly, but I see a script tag at the end that says "window.close()". Could you be tripping this by accident? I thought scripts were supposed to be declared in the header rather than the body?

Comment: I thought that might be it too, but I tried creating a new project, taking out that, as well as the entire `<form>` section of the code, but I still had the same issue. Also, it was working before with that `window.close()` prior to today.

Comment: i see, well do you know what changed? All I know is that I am pretty sure the script should be placed in the header. I can only assume you are somehow submitting your form.

Comment: I wonder if maybe your onChange methods are being triggered by adding new options? You should be able to use breakpoints in Eclipse to debug your page. I would suggest placing a break point in eventhandler and submit methods to see where the page closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is pretty silly. So I created another new jsp file, with the same code, except for the code in the `<script>` tag and everything worked fine. I then re-added the `<script>` tag and it worked fine the first time. However, the next time I went to try it, the original problem occurred again. Then when I went to remove the `<script>` tag once more, the issue still remained. So whatever reason, it seems once you add the `window.close()`, it permanently stays on the page?